# Suffix -al in adjectives

Tags: suffixes

I would be grateful to know how suffix -al affects the meaning of an adjective, i.e. `music - musical` or `academic - academical`? 
Specific rules are informative, but I want to see the whole picture.

Comment: academic is already an adjective, and 'academical' is an adjective that means something different.

Comment: English is such an irregular language. **Music** is a noun, so **musical** is the adjective. But **academic** is both a noun and an adjective, so **academical** isn't normally used (see previous comment).

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a universal rule.

In general, it doesn't change the meaning of an adjective, it makes a noun *into* an adjective.  Music is a noun, musical is an adjective. Academic is *already* an adjective. Academical is an archaic word that is not really used any more.

Because this is English, of course there are exceptions.
Historic means something important or significant in history, e.g. the moon landing was a historic event. Historical means anything referring to the past, e.g. historical data on how vaccines affected life expectancy, the historical fiction genre of literature, etc.